# Why did no Uchiha used Izanami or Izanagi during the massacre?

Tags: naruto

I feel no Uchiha showed any efforts in stopping the Uchiha massacre.

Why did no Uchiha use **Izanami** or **Izanagi** on Itachi and Obito?

Comment: Because only handful of Uchiha can use Izanagi.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Izanami and Izanagi were forbidden techniques. Also, only few among Uchiha could use them.

Moreover, Izanagi in particular had quite a large downside of blindness.

From what is shown in the Anime, people probably knew of Izanagi, but were not skilled enough to use it. Izanami was probably known to only a few people, as evidenced by Itachi and Sasuke's conversation during their fight with Kabuto.

Another issue is that both of these techniques require a bit of preparation.  The massacre by Itachi and Obito were very sudden and wildly unexpected. Thus, even if anybody had the knowledge of the techniques, I don't think they had the time to think of using them!

Comment: Good answer, a few notes to add, Izanami and Izanagi both cause blindness in the eye that uses them its not just Izanagi. Izanagi was shown to be pretty long lasting in Danzo and Tobi's hands but both have Senju cells which lengthens the duration of Izanagi, a regular Uchiha gets only a few seconds and then their eye is out of commission.